# Could not launch Simulator.app error when running unit tests in parallel with simulator already open

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, ios-simulator

When running in serial, all tests pass. When I run my unit tests in parallel without the simulator being launched, they all pass. However, when I select 6 or more tests to run simultaneously, they pass in the Test navigator, but I get a "Test failed" overlay and a popup that says "Could not launch Simulator.app". Presumably because the simulator is already launched and it's bugging. But I don't understand how this should fail my tests? Anyone else had this before?

Expanding the details gives the following:

```
Details

Could not launch Simulator.app.
Domain: DVTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain
Code: 1
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-08-10 05:13:12 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
}
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -600.)
Domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain
Code: -600
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone15,2";
    "device_osBuild" = "16.4 (20E247)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Test;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 54;
    "operation_errorCode" = 1;
    "operation_errorDomain" = DVTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 0;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 3;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 0;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.tool";
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 1;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator16.4";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "16.4";
    "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.4.1 (Build 22F82)
Xcode 14.3.1 (21815) (Build 14E300c)
Timestamp: 2023-08-10T13:13:12+08:00
```

Comment: [Similar problem on the Apple Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/723911), without any answer :/